# This error only appears when I run in Ubuntu, in windows 10 it works normal, what to do?

Tags: pandas

def trabaLinhas(caminho):

```
colunas = extraindoZip.listaArq(caminho)[1]
dadosV = pd.DataFrame(columns=colunas)
for coluna in colunas:
    listaLinhas = lerTxt(caminho, coluna)
    dadosVazao = []
    count = 0
    for linha in listaLinhas:
        count += 1
        if count == 1:
            indiceCodigo = linha.index("EstacaoCodigo")
            inicioVa = linha.index("Vazao01")
            indiceData = linha.index("Data")
            indiceCons = linha.index("NivelConsistencia")
        elif count >= 2:
            codigoEst = linha[indiceCodigo]
            data = pd.to_datetime(linha[indiceData], dayfirst=True)
            dias = ca.monthrange(data.year, data.month)[1]
            listaData = pd.date_range(data, periods=dias, freq="D")
            listaCons = [int(linha[indiceCons])]*dias
            indexMult = list(zip(*[listaData, listaCons]))
            index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indexMult, names=["Data", "Consistencia"])
            indiceVa = [i for i in range(inicioVa, inicioVa+dias)]
            listaVazao = [np.NaN if linha[i] == "" else float(linha[i].replace(",",".")) for i in indiceVa]
            dadosVazao.append(pd.Series(listaVazao, index=index))

    dadosV[coluna] = pd.concat(dadosVazao)


return dadosV
```

=====================================================================
File `/home/clebson/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py`, line 1516,

in re-index raise Exception(`cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`)
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: Please could you edit your post to include your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What happens when you add another column in the DataFrame